# Ubuntu runtime error after update

Tags: virtualbox, crash

I am using Ubuntu on VirtualBox and recently updated it, but after the update when I opened VirtualBox it got corrupted. Here is the picture of the runtime error it's showing.

[image: runtime error it's showing] 
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means VirtualBox couldn't find the VM xml files (like ubuntu.xml). Make sure the file exists and is accessible.

Comment: I searched the folder there's no such file like that. What do I do now?

Comment: The xml file is the file that has all the config settings for the VM. If it's gone, your VM is gone. Your virtual hard drive may still be there so you can create a new machine that uses that hard drive - so you won't have lost your installation. However, see if the xml file is in a different place. Open VirtualBox and go do Preferences and see what the default location is for the VM folder.

Comment: So there's one file I found with the help of preferences and it is named as "VirtualBox.xml-prev". What do I do now?

Comment: Rename it to VirtualBox.xml and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I made another machine on the same hardware, the XML method wasn't getting any better however I got all my data with a new machine. Thanks ALOT!!!

Comment: btw can I delete the previous Ubuntu machine(not the actual files but the virtual bix machine) and what precautions should I take for the next time when i update Virtual Box?

Comment: You can safely delete anything EXCEPT (!!) your virtual hard drive (which you might consider backing up anyway). I think the upgrade problem you had was a fluke. Generally speaking, VirtualBox upgrades without issue.